# How to connect to a remote service from a Docker Container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-network

My dotnet core app running in a docker container on my needs to connect to some external service via their IP one of which is an sql database running separately on a remote server hosted on google cloud. The app runs without issue when not running with docker, however with docker it fails with

```
An error occurred using the connection to database 'PartnersDb' on server '30.xx.xx.xx,39876'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Partners.Api.Infrastructure.Persistence.MoneyTransferDbContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled conn
ections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

My Docker compose file looks like this

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  my-network:
    name: my_network

services:
  partners:
    image: partners.api:latest
    container_name: partners
    build:
      context: ./
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
      - ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=30.xx.xx.xx,39876;Database=PartnersDb;User Id=don;Password=Passwor123$$
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - /Users/mine/Desktop/logs⁩:/logs
```

I have

1. bin bashed into the running container and I'm able to run pings to
   the remote sql database server
2. I've also being able to telnet to
   the remote sql database server on the database port

However, problem arises when i do docker-compose up then I get the error above.
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea is running on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

I really do not know what to do at this stage.

Comment: This post on superuser might help
https://superuser.com/questions/1286281/still-unable-to-access-internet-from-docker-containers

Comment: @SeanMorris I was running on a user defined bridge network already, even though i stripped it and used the default bridge as suggested in the link, it still didn't work.

Comment: When you ran the container & were successfully able to access the service, did you use `docker run` or `docker-compose run` ?

Comment: @SeanMorris with docker run and docker-compose up and attaching a shell to the container, I'm able to ping and telnet to the remote services. But the app itself is unable to connect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate networks. Inside docker is a separate network. Outside docker, on the host machine, it's a different network. If you are accessing it by localhost or IP address it won't work as you are expecting it.

```
docker network ls
```

will show you a similar output like below:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
58a4dd9893e9        133_default         bridge              local
424817227b42        bridge              bridge              local
739297b8107e        host                host                local
b9c4fb3ed4ba        none                null                local
```

You need to add the host for Java service locally. Try running like a below command:

#### For Service:

```
docker run --add-host remoteservice:<ip address of java service> <your image>
```

Hopefully, this will fix it.

More here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts

#### For PartnersDb Database:

If PartnersDb is a SQL database you'll have to configure SQL Server to listen to specific ports. Through SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network configuration > TCP/IP Properties.

More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15

There are similar settings for MySQL as well.

After which you'll have to run `add-host` switch

```
docker run --add-host PartnersDb:<ip address of PartnersDb database> <your image>
```

You can update the `hosts` file as well with these settings. I'd prefer it through the command line instead.

Comment: This didn't work. I have my connection string like this ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=x.x.x.x,3030;Database=MyDb;User Id=User;Password=Password. After setting the  extra_hosts:
      - "PartnersdB:x.x.x.x" in my docker compose and also trying to run with docker run, I still get the same error.

Comment: oh sorry man! Pls do network debugging inside docker you'll need `net-tools` package to do `ifconfig` and `ping` host computer. Found a few effective technique here: https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/13